# python, apscheduler, add_cron_job starts running right away

Tags: python, apscheduler

This function almost works for me, but the issue is it will always run once as soon as I start it, then it will start working as normal.  I have tried many different things to solve this such as adding in a `start_date='sometime in the future'` and it will still run one time as soon as I start the function.  Here is the general formula I am using.

```
import apscheduler

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

s = Scheduler();

s.add_cron_job(simple_print.simple_print,day_of_week='0-5',hour=18,minute='12-13' )
s.start()
```

I want this to run on days Monday to Saturday at hour 18 (6:00) at minute 12 and minute 13. The problem is if I run this a little before this time it will run once initially then after one run it will start running correctly. I have searched with Google for this issue, but maybe I am the only one who can't figure this out.

Python 2.7 and latest apscheduler.

Comment: Try enabling debug logging (logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)). That should shed some light into the situation.

Comment: would it help if you pass in start_date='xxx' argument?